# C# Using same winform for different purpose (novice)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm novice in c# and winforms, my idea is to create a simple app , which contains Form1 like this on image

[image]

There is dategridview where I can show data from database table Products(ID is not visible),then when I click on button New, Form2 will open

[image]

I want to use same Form2 when I want to edit some of the items, selecting specific row in datagridview and clicking on button Edit(I've managed to do this on 2 different win forms).How can I achieve this ?
This is what I've done so far:

button New

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.Show();
    }
```

method PerformRefresh()

```
public void PerformRefresh()
    {
        this.productsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbtestDataSet.products);
        this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Form2

```
Form1 _owner;
    public Form2(Form1 owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _owner = owner;
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosing);
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _owner.PerformRefresh();
    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = textBox1.Text;
        int Quantity = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);

        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(Konekcija.cnndbtest);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products (Name,Quantity) VALUES(@name, @quantity)", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Quantity);

        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception xcp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xcp.Message);
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Object has been successfully entered into the database", "Message");
        this.Close();
    }
```

then, for button Edit on Form1 I've made class MyProducts , and made object of this class ,which I want to pass to Form2

```
MyProducts myProducts = new MyProducts();
        myProducts.ID = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        myProducts.Name = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        myProducts.Quantity = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

Now I want to show Form2 clicking on button Edit , and when Form2 is shown, I want to have selected Item properties displayed into 2 textbox controls.
Any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give Form2 a public Property of MyProducts and fill the TextBoxes

```
private MyProducts product;
public MyProducts Product
{
  set
  {
    product = value;
    if (product != null)
    {
      nameTextBox.Text = product.Name;
      quantityTextBox.Text = product.Quantity.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then before opening the form for edit pass the MyProducts-Element you wanna edit

```
private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyProducts myProducts = new MyProducts();
    myProducts.ID = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    myProducts.Name = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    myProducts.Quantity = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
    f2.Product = myProducts;
    f2.Show();
}
```

then on safe check if product has value to determine update or insert

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = textBox1.Text;
    int Quantity = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    if (product != null)
    {
      //SQL Update command
    }
    else
    {
      //SQL Insert command
    }

    //SQL Execute
}
```

hope this helps